# how do i get the comments from a post in facebook with an access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Please help me out here, i am a noob going nuts on Facebook API calls...

I want to retrieve the comments of a post that i posted on another users fan or personal page.

I have its long lived access token.
I debugged it with the Facebook access token debugger to see if it is valid, and it expires in 2 months.

I have the following permissions:
`public_profile`, `basic_info`, `rsvp_event`, `email`, `read_friendlists`, `manage_pages`, `publish_actions`, `user_birthday`, `user_relationships`, `user_location`, `user_likes`, `user_activities`, `user_website`, `user_friends` & `user_about_me`

I would like to get the comments of a post the id is `100006454706505_1649297628628711`
which is returned to me by a post i previously made.

What is the facebook api call i need to make to read the comments and likes of that post?
It looks so simple a question....

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
        'appId' => __FB_APP_ID__,
        'secret' => __FB_SECRET_APP_ID__
    ));
$result = $facebook->api('/me/posts', array('access_token' => $access_token, 'limit' => 100));
```

output:

```
data: array = 
    0: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1613262798898861
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels likes a link.
      story_tags: array = 
        0: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006454706505
            name: string = Kc Hessels
            offset: long = 0
            length: long = 10
            type: string = user
      privacy: array = 
        value: string = 
      type: string = status
      created_time: string = 2014-05-26T23:43:51+0000
      updated_time: string = 2014-05-26T23:43:51+0000
    1: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1607721539452987
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels and Elizabeth Garita are now friends.
      story_tags: array = 
        0: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006454706505
            name: string = Kc Hessels
            offset: long = 0
            length: long = 10
            type: string = user
        15: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100007895078419
            name: string = Elizabeth Garita
            offset: long = 15
            length: long = 16
            type: string = user
      actions: array = 
        0: array = 
          name: string = Comment
          link: string = https://www.facebook.com/100006454706505/posts/1607721539452987
      privacy: array = 
        value: string = 
      type: string = status
      status_type: string = approved_friend
      created_time: string = 2014-05-19T19:37:46+0000
      updated_time: string = 2014-05-19T19:37:46+0000
    2: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1578102925748182
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels and Nuemy Del Carmen Ramirez Varela are now friends.
      story_tags: array = 
        0: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006454706505
            name: string = Kc Hessels
            offset: long = 0
            length: long = 10
            type: string = user
        15: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006041622188
            name: string = Nuemy Del Carmen Ramirez Varela
            offset: long = 15
            length: long = 31
            type: string = user
      actions: array = 
        0: array = 
          name: string = Comment
          link: string = https://www.facebook.com/100006454706505/posts/1578102925748182
      privacy: array = 
        value: string = 
      type: string = status
      status_type: string = approved_friend
      created_time: string = 2014-04-11T17:25:51+0000
      updated_time: string = 2014-04-11T17:25:51+0000
    3: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1534063350152140
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels is now friends with Jocseline Kassandra Ulate and Monte Campana Carros.
      story_tags: array = 
        0: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006454706505
            name: string = Kc Hessels
            offset: long = 0
            length: long = 10
            type: string = user
        31: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100001919869875
            name: string = Jocseline Kassandra Ulate
            offset: long = 31
            length: long = 25
            type: string = user
        61: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100007783835968
            name: string = Monte Campana Carros
            offset: long = 61
            length: long = 20
            type: string = user
      privacy: array = 
        value: string = 
      type: string = status
      status_type: string = approved_friend
      created_time: string = 2014-02-20T17:42:25+0000
      updated_time: string = 2014-02-20T17:42:25+0000
    4: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1528673807357761
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels and Icam Capacitaciones are now friends.
      story_tags: array = 
        0: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006454706505
            name: string = Kc Hessels
            offset: long = 0
            length: long = 10
            type: string = user
        15: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100004980821986
            name: string = Icam Capacitaciones
            offset: long = 15
            length: long = 19
            type: string = user
      actions: array = 
        0: array = 
          name: string = Comment
          link: string = https://www.facebook.com/100006454706505/posts/1528673807357761
      privacy: array = 
        value: string = 
      type: string = status
      status_type: string = approved_friend
      created_time: string = 2014-02-11T18:29:16+0000
      updated_time: string = 2014-02-11T18:29:16+0000
    5: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1525634190995056
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels likes Hotel Club & Resort Monte Campana and Coupon-promotions.
      story_tags: array = 
        0: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 100006454706505
            name: string = Kc Hessels
            offset: long = 0
            length: long = 10
            type: string = user
        17: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 168932636493309
            name: string = Hotel Club & Resort Monte Campana
            offset: long = 17
            length: long = 33
            type: string = page
        55: array = 
          0: array = 
            id: string = 1384288225125264
            name: string = Coupon-promotions
            offset: long = 55
            length: long = 17
            type: string = page
      privacy: array = 
        value: string = 
      type: string = status
      application: array = 
        name: string = Pages
        id: string = 2530096808
      created_time: string = 2014-02-06T20:55:28+0000
      updated_time: string = 2014-02-06T20:55:28+0000
    6: array = 
      id: string = 100006454706505_1524425311115944
      from: array = 
        id: string = 100006454706505
        name: string = Kc Hessels
      story: string = Kc Hessels likes Coupon-promotions and 2 other Pages.
      story_tags: array =
```

( i feel like i miss the bloody obvious)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after fiddling somewhat with it, i found the answer... I get a lot of data, and one piece of data contains the post.

Is there a way to get the post directly, without iterating the whole feed ?